# Rotate and crop image batch

Tags: php

EDIT: please forget about this question! I made a stupid error in the original code.
The example code works as expected!

I'm trying to rotate AND crop images.
I have this so far:

```
$w = 100;
$h = 400;
$img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('image1.jpg');
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg('image2.jpg');
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    ${'img'.$i + 3} = imagecreatetruecolor($h, $h);
    imagecopy(${'img'.$i + 3}, ${'img'.$i + 1}, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
    ${'img'.$i + 3} = imagerotate(${'img'.$i + 3}, 90, 0);
    ${'img'.$i + 3} = imagecrop(${'img'.$i + 3}, array(0, 0, $h, $w));
    imagejpeg(${'img'.$i + 3});
    imagedestroy(${'img'.$i + 3});
    imagedestroy(${'img'.$i + 1});
}
```

So what I essentially do is open some JPGs, create new images, copy the JPGs into the new images and then crop the images.

Alas this results in empty images ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and are you getting errors in the log?

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this will make any difference to the lack of output - but what do `$img1` & `$img2` do - they don't get used as far as i can see?

```
@error_reporting( E_ALL );
$w = 100;
$h = 400;

$img1 = imagecreatefromjpeg('image1.jpg');
$img2 = imagecreatefromjpeg('image2.jpg');

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

        $new=${'img'.$i + 3};
        $src=${'img'.$i + 1};


    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($h, $h);
    imagecopy( $new, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

    $new = imagerotate($new, 90, 0);
    $new = imagecrop($new, array(0, 0, $h, $w));

    imagejpeg($new);

    imagedestroy($new);
    imagedestroy($src);

    break;/* just to see if it gets this far*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it was an error I made in the original code I wrote ... BTW: just as a comment on your question about `$img1` and `$img2`, these were referenced in the line `$src=${'img'.$i + 1};`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should consider using [image copy resampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) for a better quality of result from the process.

Then, you need to correctly use the [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) function, currently you are simply loading the JPGs and outputting them directly, which may be what you want but you're in a loop and you can't loop load multiple images directly to the same file. It also means that the image you're seeing (or not) is the final image in the set.

Your Problem is that your `for` loop runs THREE times but your only have data associated with the first two instances, but the third instance is empty, and as this is the most recent this is the only instance output to the browser.

So:

1) Save the images you have generated with `imagejpeg($data,$filename);`. You can define a filename as `$filename = $img+3.".jpg";` or similar.

2) It would also be much easier to debug and read your code if you used arrays instead of numerically incremented variables, that's a very messy way of writing code!

3) If you do want to output the image directly to the browser you need PHP to supply a header such as `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` *before* outputting the contents of `imagejpeg`.

---

**A Rehash of your code:**

```
$w = 100;
$h = 400;
$img[1] = imagecreatefromjpeg('image1.jpg');
$img[2] = imagecreatefromjpeg('image2.jpg');
for ($i = 3; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $img[$i] = imagecreatetruecolor($h, $h);
    $j = $i -2;
    imagecopyresampled($img[$i], $img[$j], 0, 0, 0, 0, $h, $h, $w, $h,);
    // this function also contains destination width and destination 
    // height, which are equal to the size of the destination image so 
    // are set as $h, $h in the function above. 
    $img[$i] = imagerotate($img[$i], 90, 0);
    $img[$i] = imagecrop($img[$i], array(0, 0, $h, $w));
    $filename = "image-".$i.".jpg";
    imagejpeg($img[$i], $filename);
    imagedestroy($img[$i]);
    imagedestroy($img[$j]);
}
```

Comment: I'm really ashamed, I made an error in the original code :( The code I pasted here was simplified for the example. So when I tried that it worked. Anyway, thanks for the tip using the array, that's really much neater.